# Testing if an asset image exists, and falling back to a network image

Tags: flutter

I have the following function that attempts to load an image asset, falling back to loading it over the network if it doesn't exist:

```
Widget loadSvgWithFallbackToCdn(String path,
      {double width, double height, Function placeholderBuilder}) {
    try {
      return SvgPicture.asset(
        path,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        placeholderBuilder: placeholderBuilder,
      );
    } catch(e) {
      return SvgPicture.network(
        '$CDN_URL/$path',
        height: height,
        width: width,
        placeholderBuilder: placeholderBuilder,
      );
    }
  }
```

The issue is that the resulting "Unable to load asset" exception is not processed by the `catch(e)` block:

[image: exception outside catch(e) block]

How can I handle missing asset images gracefully (seamlessly falling back to a CDN hosted image)?

Comment: This answer might be useful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50685617/3925977

Comment: That was helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up creating a custom SvgLoader class that looks like this:

```
class SvgLoader {
  static Widget withFallback(String localPath, String networkPath) =>
      FutureBuilder(
        future: _futureAssetWithFallback(localPath, networkPath),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) =>
            snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );

  static Future<SvgPicture> _futureAssetWithFallback(
          String localPath, String networkPath) async =>
      (await isLocalAsset(localPath))
          ? SvgPicture.asset(localPath)
          : SvgPicture.network(networkPath);

  // Test if a file exists without throwing an Exception
  static Future<bool> isLocalAsset(String assetPath) async {
    try {
      await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath);
      return true;
    } catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
          child: SvgLoader.withFallback("assets/images/cow.svg",
              "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2194/2194805.svg")),
    );
  }
```